# Simulating data from skewed distribution with zeros

Tags: distributions, simulation

I have some sample data:

```
   dat <- c(3, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 6, 9, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 5, 9, 1, 1, 0, 12, 2, 5, 3, 8, 10, 2, 5, 0, 0, 6, 1, 0, 10, 
5, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 9, 2, 4, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 1, 7, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 0, 6, 11, 5, 0, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 
1, 10, 2, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 4, 10, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 
3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 8, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 0, 5, 0, 3, 
0, 5, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1, 4, 7, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 5, 6, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0)
```

The histogram looks like this:

[image]

The data correspond to some measure of disability and is capped at 12. I'm trying to simulate data for a treated sample (e.g. the above data) and a control sample (e.g. median of the distribution is shifted to the right by 1).

**Question**
Is there a way to simulate the *control sample* non-parametrically? I want to preserve the zeros, so I cannot simply bootstrap and add 1 to the values. Another option is using some mixture - atom at zero and some distribution $F^+$ on the non-zero part, but it's hard to know what the proportion of zeros and non-zeros will be in the control sample.

Comment: Well, the median of `dat` is 1. So if you want a simulation with a median of 2 and keeping the zeros, then your simulation should have 103 zeros, then about 41 samples from 1 and 2, then 102 data points sampled from 3-12, e.g. using the empirical distribution in `dat`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: In that scenario, the proportion of zeros is the same between the two samples, which is not necessarily what I would expect between the two samples. I guess that would be another simulation parameter that would need to be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your dataset `dat`.

I am assuming you want a fictitious control sample `ctrl`, of about the same size $n = 246$ as `dat`, of similar shape, but with a sample median of $2$ instead of $1.$ Also, I'm assuming you'd want to use a two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum
test (*not* a paired Wilcoxon signed rank test) to compare the two samples:
actual `dat` and fictitious `ctrl`.

Depending on the mechanism for decreasing scores from `ctrl` to `dat` you have in mind, there would be many ways
to simulate the fictitious sample `ctrl`. One would be that `ctrl` would
be $0, 1$ or $2$ points higher than `dat`, but without exceeding $12.$

Importing your dataset `dat` into R, I get the following summary for `dat`.

```
summary(dat)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   0.000   1.000   1.963   3.000  12.000 
n = length(dat);  n
[1] 246
table(dat)
dat
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
103  41  31  18   9  21   7   3   4   3   4   1   1
```

Then increase the *non-zero* `dat` scores by $0,1,$ or $2$ in appropriate proportions to get a preliminary `ctrl.1`.

```
ctrl.1 = dat[dat>0]
table(ctrl.1)
ctrl.1
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
41 31 18  9 21  7  3  4  3  4  1  1 

set.seed(2021)
ctrl.1 = ctrl.1 + sample(0:2, 143, rep=T, p=c(1,2,2))
table(ctrl.1)
ctrl.1
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
 7 30 27 20 15 10 17  6  4  2  1  4
```

At this point it would be possible to have a few scores above 12.
If so, either drop them or maintain the same sample size by changing them to 12.

Now put the $0$'s back, and see what summary we have.

```
ctrl = c(rep(0,103), ctrl)
summary(ctrl)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   0.000   2.000   2.622   4.000  12.000
```

The sample median and upper quartile are
increased by about $1,$ as desired.
Here are boxplots (`dat` at left) of the two samples. They seem to
have similar shapes. Also, the nonoverlapping notches in the sides
of the boxes indicate that the two medians may be significantly different at the 5% level.

```
boxplot(dat, ctrl, notch=T, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

Moreover, a two-sample Wilcoxon RS test can distinguishing
between datasets `dat` and `ctrl`; the P-value is $0.042 < 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
wilcox.test(dat, ctrl)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  dat and ctrl
W = 27182, p-value = 0.04222
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: But just before a long phone call, I discovered I didn't preserve your 0's. So now I'm working on a slight modification of the same idea that does preserve 0's. ... OK, the revision is now in place and I hope your specifications are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks! Your base answer was clear enough for me to modify it in a similar way as the update. I like the strategy of adding (0,1,2).